# Why is nginx serving content from the wrong server_name?

Tags: nginx

We migrated one of our websites last friday to a new server which runs nginx 1.10.3 + ngx_pagespeed 1.11.33.4:

Nginx has two hosts configured:

1. **PHPMyAdmin - pma.mydomainname.com**

   ```
       server {

           listen 80;

           server_name pma.MYDOMAINNAME.com;

           root /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
           index index.php;

           # set expiration of assets to MAX for caching
           location ~* \.(ico|css|js)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {

               expires max;
               log_not_found off;
           }

           location ~* \.php$ {

               fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
               fastcgi_index index.php;
               fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
               include fastcgi_params;
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           }
       }
   ```
2. **The Website itself - www.MYDOMAINNAME.com**

   ```
       server {
           listen 80;

           server_name MYDOMAINNAME.com www.MYDOMAINNAME;

           return 301 https://www.MYDOMAINNAME.com$request_uri;
       }

       server {

           listen 443 ssl http2;

           server_name www.MYDOMAINNAME.com;

           ssl on;
           ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.ca-bundle;
           ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.key;
           ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
           ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
           ssl_dhparam  /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
           ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;
           ssl_session_timeout 1h;

           error_log /var/log/nginx/DOMAIN_error.log debug;
           access_log /var/log/nginx/DOMAIN_access.log;

           root /var/www/www.MYDOMAINNAME.com/web;
           client_max_body_size 25M;

           ######################################################################
           ################################ PAGE SPEEEED ########################
           ######################################################################

           pagespeed on;
           pagespeed FileCachePath /var/cache/pagespeed;
           pagespeed Domain https://www.MYDOMAINNAME.com;
           pagespeed Domain https://CDN.MYDOMAINNAME.com;
           pagespeed SupportNoScriptEnabled false;
           pagespeed EnableFilters combine_css;
           pagespeed EnableFilters combine_javascript;
           pagespeed EnableFilters prioritize_critical_css;
           pagespeed EnableFilters extend_cache;
           pagespeed EnableFilters make_google_analytics_async;
           pagespeed EnableFilters collapse_whitespace;
           pagespeed XHeaderValue "CUSTOM HEADER";

           # Ensure requests for pagespeed optimized resources go to the pagespeed handler
           # and no extraneous headers get set.
           location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" {
               add_header "" "";
           }

           location ~ "^/pagespeed_static/" { }
           location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon$" { }


           ######################################################################
           ################################ STATIC FILES ########################
           ######################################################################

           add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains" always;

           location / {
               try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
           }

           location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|eot|ttf|woff|woff2|svg)$ {
               add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
               expires 365d;
               try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
           }

           ######################################################################
           ################################ SYMFONY #############################
           ######################################################################

           location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
               fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
               fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
               include fastcgi_params;
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
           }

           location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
               fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
               fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
               include fastcgi_params;
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
               internal;
           }

           location ~ \.php$ {
               rewrite (.*) /app.php/not-found;
           }
   ```

   }

Because we've seen a 30% drop of traffic during the weekend I took a look into the logs and I've seen some weird messages:

```
2017/04/03 06:24:47 [error] 6667#6667: *1093138 open() "/usr/share/phpmyadmin/FULL-REQUEST-PATH-HERE" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: <IP>, server: pma.MYDOMAINMANE.com, request: "GET /FULL-REQUEST-PATH-HERE HTTP/1.1", host: "www.MYDOMAINNAME.com"
```

It's basically routing a request to www.MYDOMAINNAME.com to pma.MYDOMAINNAME.com but the hostname in the request headers is in fact www.MYDOMAINNAME.com

Comment: Use `nginx -T` to see the full configuration as read by `nginx`. Double check your `server_name` directive, your question has a typo - does the actual file?

Comment: @RichardSmith, could you point out the type in my question? If it's a replaced domain name, I might have introduced it when I changed the config before posting it.

I ran nginx -T and everything seems in order. The weird thing is once I disabled the virtual host pma.MYDOMAINNAME.com I saw a direct impact in our traffic ( realtime google analytics ).

And a weirder thing is I don't know how to reproduce it. Everything worked fine for me before disabling the virtual host.

Comment: Missing .com in your www domain.

Comment: @RichardSmith, the typo was in the original config as well, I am amazed I did not see it. I fixed it, enabled the pma virtual host and I am monitoring the logs to catch any error. Thanks!